# C#, Write in a .txt file, without deleting the previous line

Tags: c#

Basicly I'm writing a fake malware, which will write in a .txt the Session username of the person which clicked on it. The problem is that when someone execute it will erase the previous lines.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Text = "Fake Malware";
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string createText = " just clicked on the fake Malware";
        File.WriteAllText("//vm-files/users/ngallouj/zig/zig.txt", Environment.UserName + createText + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
        string readText = File.ReadAllText("//vm-files/users/ngallouj/zig/zig.txt");


    }

    private void zig(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("Link to a warning message on click, nothing important.");
        string createText = " just clicked on the fake Malware";
        File.WriteAllText("//vm-files/users/ngallouj/zig/zig.txt", Environment.UserName+ createText + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
        string readText = File.ReadAllText("//vm-files/users/ngallouj/zig/zig.txt");

    }
}
```

Comment: Use [`File.AppendAllText`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.appendalltext?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead of `File.WriteAllText`

Comment: Working fine thanks ! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is AppendAllText:

```
File.AppendAllText("//vm-files/users/ngallouj/zig/zig.txt", "Wow it worked :)");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is the fix
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string createText = " just clicked on the fake Malware";
        File.AppendAllText("//vm-files/users/ngallouj/zig/zig.txt", Environment.UserName + createText + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
        string readText = File.ReadAllText("//vm-files/users/ngallouj/zig/zig.txt");


    }

    private void zig(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("#");
        string createText = " just clicked on the fake Malware";
        File.AppendAllText("//vm-files/users/ngallouj/zig/zig.txt", Environment.UserName+ createText + " " + DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt"));
        string readText = File.ReadAllText("//vm-files/users/ngallouj/zig/zig.txt");

    }
}
```

}